# Forge Viewer button with text

Tags: autodesk-viewer

What's the simplest way of making a button with text instead of an icon? So that it still fits in with the overall UI control system, e.g. can be added to a ComboButton or a Toolbar. The API doesn't seem to have any official way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the HTML element (`container`) of your button directly and code against it (e.g. `innerText`) like:

```
button.container.innerText=233
```

[image]